# Derived class method from base class pointer : some alternatives?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I know this kind of question has been answered a few times, but I am giving the context of the problem to expect some other architecture alternatives.

Consider a class CExpression:

```
class CExpression
{
    public:
        ...
    private:
        vector<CComponent*> components_;
        string expression_;
}
```

CExpression has to decompose the string, which represents a mathematical expression (e.g. "y = x + 5"), into the vector ("y", '=', "x", '+', 5). To do so, the vector is composed of CComponent pointers, which can point to objects of class CVariable, COperator and CConstant.
Obviously, CComponent is an abstract class and the base class of the three classes mentioned above. So, after parsing the string, the vector should contains the following in order (semi pseudocode of the process):

```
components_.push_back(new CVariable("y"));
components_.push_back(new COperator('='));
components_.push_back(new CVariable("x"));
components_.push_back(new COperator('+'));
components_.push_back(new CConstant( 5 ));
```

The use of the polymorphism here is to have the expression decomposed into a single vector (which will facilitate the future parsing processes). However, some of the derived classes have unique features that others don't have, making it impossible to implement these features in the base class (CComponent).

For instance, consider the COperator class:

```
class COperator : public CComponent
{
    public:
        int GetPriority() const { return prority_; }
        ...
    private:
        int priority_;
        ...
}
```

Priority, which represents the priority the operator will have to be parsed from the vector, is unique to this class (hence no virtual function in the base class). Now let's come to the problem.

Consider the CComponent class (base class):

```
enum Type { VARIABLE, OPERATOR, CONSTANT };

class CComponent
{
    public:
        Type GetType() const { return type_; }
        ...
    private:
        Type type_;
        ...
}
```

Type, which is common to any component of the expression, represents the type of the component (e.g. if it is a CVariable, the type would then be set to VARIABLE at construction).

Finally, consider this CExpression method (fictional):

```
void CExpression::Process()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < components_.size(); i++)
    {
        if (components_[i] -> GetType() == OPERATOR)
        {
            cout << components_[i] -> GetPriority(); // won't work
        }
    }
}
```

In fact, since I can only use the methods of the pointer's type class (except if I dynamic_cast, which I think is not the most beautiful way), I have two questions:

1. Is there a proper way to do what I want to achieve or the dynamic_cast is my only option ?
2. Should I adopt a completely different program architecture to counter this problem ? If yes, what should I do ?

By the way I know it could have been more simple to explain, but I tought the context would be a great helper to seize the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: I think a tree structure is more appropriate for the kinds of expressions you are trying to capture.

Comment: I guess there are some options: a) You might want to consider having *all* the methods in the base class, making the invalid one throw an exception or returning an error where they're not applicable, b) You might want to consider using the [visitor pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/visitor-pattern.html) or the [command pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/command-pattern.html)... both are cases of hiding different behaviours under a common interface.

Comment: This is a classical case for the Visitor pattern.

Answer (score 3):

I guess, that your architecture won't fit your needs - especially when you'll start to expand it.

I have some experience in processing mathematical expressions and I'd say, that the most natural way of storing expressions is a tree. Each terminal item (such as number or a variable) is a leaf of the tree and each non-terminal item (such as operator or a function call) is a node, which has children. For instance:

```
y = x + 5
```

Should be translated into tree:

```
  =
 / \
y   +
   / \
  x   5
```

What are the benefits of such structure? Firstly, it's a lot easier to evaluate than a vector of tokens. Secondly, such things as operator priorities or direction of association matter only while building this structure - they are not used when the structure is built and ready for evaluation. Then, each node does not care about what is attached to it as children, it simply lets them evaluate themselves and when it is done it ends up with a list of terminal items on which it can work. Even assignment operator can perform its work (of course, if you pass to it some kind of context containing list of variables).

Creating such structure is very easy if you use well-known Reverse Polish Notation algorithm.

In your case I'd vote on complete rearrangement of your data structure to one, which is a lot better one for storing expressions.

And one more thing. Also from my experience, I'd strongly suggest, that you create **different classes** for these three things:

- An item read from the input ( = a token)
- An item held in the expression tree ( = an expression item)
- An item being a partial result while evaluating the tree ( = an eval object)

This may seem like complicating your architecture, but will actually simplify your work and allow your architecture to be a lot more flexible.

A **rough draft** of structure:

```
class BaseNode
{
public:
    virtual EvalObject Eval() = 0;

    // This method is handy when working with assignment operator.
    // For instance, Eval() called on variable will return its value
    // but EvalLHS() will return a reference to variable. 
    virtual EvalObject EvalLHS() = 0;
};

class Operator : BaseNode
{

};

class BinaryOperator : Operator
{
private:
    BaseNode * leftChild;
    BaseNode * rightChild;
};

class Add : BinaryOperator
{
public:
    void Eval()
    {
        auto left = leftChild->Eval(); // Eval RHS, 
        auto right = rightChild->Eval(); // Eval RHS

        // Now perform calculations on left and right
        // depending on their types
    }

    void EvalLHS()
    {
        throw InvalidOperationException("Cannot perform LHS evaluation on adding operator");
    }
}

class Assign : BinaryOperator
{
public:
    void Eval()
    {
        auto left = leftChild->EvalLHS();
        auto right = rightChild->Eval();

        // Perform assignment

        // This is required such that operations
        // like a = b = 7 will also work
        return right;
    }

    void EvalLHS()
    {
        // Assignment cannot be on the LHS of operation, eg.
        // (a = 5) = 8 is wrong

        throw InvalidOperationException("Assignment cannot be LHS");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the design is poor and here I'll explain why:
The moment you entered the `enum Type` you actually admit that although you want to have a pure interface that work **equally** on **any** derived class - you can't do it. The algorithm implemented in the base class really *need* to know the exact type of the derived in order to do its role. In this aspect `enum Type` and `dynamic_cast` serve the same idiom: implementation that is depended on exact types.
***This is not the object oriented way***

The object oriented way claims that your algorithm, your code, the function that works with some base class as an input, assumes nothing about the real object behind the interface - only its interface matters.
As for your specific question, and as it was mentioned above, me too think that a tree-like structure would best fit this problem. There are few ways to do so. As I see it, working with it has two phases: 1. building the structure; 2. do some evaluations on the structure.
I'll try to only sketch (will not compile) what I have in mind, details and fine tuning are left to you:

```
class Expression
{
};    

class Constant : public Expression
{
    public:
        // 'int' can be easily changed to generic type 'T'
        Constant( int value ) : _value( value ) {}

    private:
        int _value;
};

class Operator : public Expression
{
    public:
        Operator( Expression left, Expression right )
            : _left( left ), _right( right ) {}

    protected:
        Expression _left;
        Expression _right;
};

class OperatorPlus : public Expression
{
    public:
        OperatorPlus( Expression left, Expression right )
            : Operator(_left( left ), _right( right )) {} 
};

// few more operators, the same
class OperatorMinus : public Expression { /* ... */ }
class OperatorMul : public Expression { /* ... */ }
class OperatorDiv : public Expression { /* ... */ }


class Variable : public Expression
{
    public:
        // string can be easily changed to generic type 'T'
        Constant( string value ) : _value( value ) {}

    private:
        string _value; 
}


void f()
{
    // y = x + 5
    OperatorEqual s1( Variable( "y" ), OperatrPlus( Variable( "x" ), Constant( 5 ) ) );
}
```

As for actually *doing* something with it. I think the best would be to add the needed functionality in the `Expression` class:

```
class Expression
{
    public:
        virtual Expression eval() = 0;
}
```

and derived can easily implement it:

```
class OperatorPlus : public Expression
{
    public:
        OperatorPlus( Expression left, Expression right )
            : Operator(_left( left ), _right( right )) {} 

    virtual Expression eval()
    {
        return _left.eval() + _right.eval();
    }
}
```

Other interfaces to `Expression` may be `print` or `shorten` or `combineEqual` or whatever fits your domain.

Comment: This looks fine to me. However, the way you implemented the structure in void f() forces you to know in advance in what order are the operators in the expression. In other words, I don't how to make it work from a string input, hence the vector I firstly did to store the decomposed expression. Any example of implementation with a string expression?

Comment: As for knowing in advanced: you can easily add a class that have an "add" operation - see @Spook answer for instance. As for string input: you need to write an algorithm that scans the input text, finds the root of the expression (e.g equal sign) and then create and "add" the new Expression to the total. Notice that when the root was found, you now have two Expressions, left and right to seek the root in them. This is a recursive operation.